# Python connecting to remote SQL server

Tags: python, mysql

I am having issues connecting to a remote SQL server.

```
dbconfig = {
  'user': 'dbuser',
  'password': 'password',
  'host': '123.45.6.789',
  'database': 'dbname',
```

}

```
def import_prices():
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**dbconfig)
    cur = cnx.cursor()
```

The error I am getting is:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): 
Access denied for user dbuser'@'12-34-45-555-dynamic.agg1.roc.bbh-prp.eircom.net' 
(using password: YES)
```

I don't know why it is adding my hostname (from internet connection) to the user. The database was set up in cPanel and when I connect from it from within the server I just use localhost.

Answer (score 1):

Likely this is not a Python or remote issue, but rather that you need to configure the mySQL server to accept connections for `dbuser` from either all hosts your specific host (IP).

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Colin, you probably need to do something like below:

CREATE USER 'dbuser'@'123.45.6.789' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbname.* TO 'dbuser'@'123.45.6.789';